# How to read part of a html coded article from database like MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to write a blog system. The main page is consist of part of the content of blog entries.

The problem is how could I make sure the excerpt is truncated correctly, since the blog entries is stored in HTML code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use `strip_tags()` to remove the HTML from it and show only the first 300 or so characters using `substr`. Otherwise you'd have to parse the HTML to break it at an appropriate place so as not to break the rest of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

**strip_tags()** and **wordwrap()**

```
<?php
$blog_entry = '<div class="myclass"><p><h1>I am trying to write a blog system.</h1> The main page is consist of part of the content of blog entries.</p>    
<p>The problem is how could I make sure the excerpt is truncated correctly, since the blog entries is stored in HTML code.</p>
<p>Thanks.</p></div>';

// Allow a couple of tags (<p>,<a>), or don't - wrap excerpts into your own CSS class in your UI

$thisExcerpt = wordwrap(strip_tags($blog_entry, '<p>,<a>'),50);
$thisExcerpt = explode("\n", $thisExcerpt);
$thisExcerpt = $thisExcerpt[0];

echo $thisExcerpt . '...';
?>
```

Outputs :

```
I am trying to write a blog system. The main...
```